# Use Equation Variable in Codeiginiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys I tried to use the variable equation on Codeigniter as in the code I wrote below, Is my code writing correct? and here's my code so far I wanna using variable $amount in my controller

In Controller

```
$amount = $this->m_data->getTotalSales->$data['TOTAL_SALES'];
```

and this in Model

```
//GET TOTAL REVENUE
function getTotalSales(){ 
$this->db->select("(SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM sales_order WHERE member = ".$this->session->userdata('ID').") - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment WHERE member_id = ".$this->session->userdata('ID').")  AS total_sales");

$query = $this->db->get(); 
    if ($query->num_rows() >0){ 
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {

            $hasilSemua[] = $data;
        }
    return $hasilSemua; 
    }
}
```

Comment: not correct bro

Comment: where is part not correct ?

Comment: you want count result ?

Comment: yups after count the result in Model , I wanna use that in controller as Variable $amount...

Comment: answer update check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amount = $this->m_data->getTotalSales();

function getTotalSales(){ 

        $result1 = $this->db->select_sum("grand_total")
                           ->from('sales_order')
                           ->where("member = $this->session->userdata('ID')");
                           ->get();


        $result2 = $this->db->select_sum("amount")
                            ->from('payment')
                            ->where("member_id = $this->session->userdata('ID')")
                            ->get();    

        return $result1->row()-$result2->row(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna use result "total_sales" in queries that I've made in Model

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after. Note that I pass the UserID in as the second parameter to the WHERE function. This is in case there is any chance of the user having inputted it (always safter to do this anyway).

```
//GET TOTAL REVENUE
function getTotalSales(){ 
$db = $this->db;

    $db->select('SUM(grand_total)');
    $db->where('member',$this->session->userdata('ID'));
    $q1 = $db->get_compiled_select('sales_order');

    $db->select('SUM(amount)');
    $db->where('member_id',$this->session->userdata('ID'));
    $q2 = $db->get_compiled_select('payment');

    $query = $db->query("SELECT ($q1) - ($q2) as total_sales");
    $data = $query->row_array();

return $data['total_sales']; 
}
```

You can then call `$amount = $this->m_data->getTotalSales;` to get your result.